# How to connect pop3 server via http proxy?

Tags: python, http, proxy, pop3, poplib

I am using poplib to receive email but my computer accesses internet via http proxy. It seems that poplib does not support proxy? How to use poplib using http proxy? Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643367/error-when-using-poplib-to-get-email/4643901#4643901